# If I subtract a number (from a sequence) from the average of all the numbers in that sequence - what do I have?

Tags: terminology, average

If I have a number (from a sequence) and I then subtract that number from the average of that sequence- what do I have? I would describe it as a 'deviation from the average' - but is there a better term for this?

For example - If I add all numbers in a sequence and divide them by the count of the numbers in the series I get an average.

Comment: Do you mean a sequence instead of a series?

Comment: Yes - sorry series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These deviations are usually called the errors or **[residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals)**. (The distinction between these two terms becomes important if your sequence is a sampling from a probability distribution, in which case error is measured with respect to the true mean instead of the sample mean.)